# Preferable number of cursor.excute() statement for a cursor in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am new to cx_Oracle and I referred [Mastering Oracle+Python, Part 1: Querying Best Practices](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html)  . Now, under the section **Cursor Objects** , the doc says, and I quote

> "You can define an arbitrary number of cursors using the cursor() method of the Connection object. Simple programs will do fine with just a single cursor, which can be used over and over again. Larger projects might however require several distinct cursors."

Now this seems very subjective, may someone please point how many cursor.execute() statements are okay with a single cursor, should every cursor
be connected and closed for every execute statement to be on safer side, something like this.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('some query - insert,delete,upate,select')
#result = cursor.fetchall() # or some other way to obtain result if required
cursor.close()
```

OR something like a cursor for every function and reuse that cursor to execute statements in that particular function.

And does the type of query also affect the choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform as many cursor.execute() method calls as desirable on a single cursor, and you do not need to close the cursor after each execution. Each cursor requires a certain amount of memory and there is a certain amount of compute time required to open/close cursors, but these are relatively small amounts. In most programs this is not an issue.

Hope that answers your questions!

Answer (score 1):

The statement you quoted is right, define as many as you need, but if your code need just one then use one. 
Keep in mind that a cursor is using memory, so the less you use the better.
If you need to have 2 cursors opened at the same time then do it, if one is sufficient then use 1.

Comment: May you answer the question as well, how many cursor.execute() are okay between the creation and close statement.

Comment: as much as query you need to execute, there is not limit or acceptable number.

Comment: So by the statement "Simple programs will do fine with just a single cursor" means create a cursor and execute it any number of times and then close it. May you also refer me to a blog or doc that explains cursor well. I read http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html but that doesn't explain what is the use of cursor, what connection.cursor do and other relevant things.

Comment: see it as a database context needed to execute your statements

Comment: Can you please elaborate, your statements are little terse, probably because I am newbie

Comment: Here is a definition of what is a database cursor:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(databases)